# Stack Overflow "GamerTag" WordPress Widget

Tags: discussion, addon

Using my incredibly shoddy PHP skills, combined with my staggeringly shallow knowledge of WordPress I've put together a Widget that shows Name, Gravatar and Rep in an [XBox Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_Live) "GamerTag" style display.

It's using a screen scraper as I couldn't see a better way to do it, but hopefully it should work for most people. I initially created it as something to use myself, so I haven't done a huge amount of testing, but if anyone has ideas/fixes/problems/anything else feel free to post.

More details and download [here](http://www.grumpydev.com/2009/01/09/stack-overflow-wordpress-widget/).

I've made a few changes in response to a few comments, and also removed the little place holder and badges in there. It takes into account badges that have been awarded multiple times, so it *should* be the same as your Stack Overflow page.

I've uploaded v2.0.0 to WordPress. It implements caching and uses the Stack Overflow JSON feed, rather than the old screen scraping method. This cuts the load on the Stack Overflow servers, reduces the data transferred to your blog and should make it less fragile if the Stack Overflow guys decide to rework the look and feel.

Comment: Please ask a more specific question. This is too general to be answered on this site

Comment: It's not a question, it's a post about a Stack Overflow 3rd part tool, as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248296/what-third-party-tools-exist-to-use-with-stackoverflow in the FAQ, and every other thing in the so-tool tag.. it's even tagged not-a-question!

Comment: I've installed it and activated it, but I don't know how to configure it. I'm using WP 2.7.

Comment: @nobody - If you go into Appearance, Widgets and add click Add, a box will appear on the right of the widget screen for you to configure it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the HTML standard, there is no `_new` as target. There is only `_blank`, `_self`, `_parent` or `_top`. So, it should be `target="_blank"` instead.

Comment: You're right, I was being an idiot.. and I write web apps for living :D

Comment: Actually, target can also be used to specify which frame/window to use....

Comment: Yes Kevin, target specifies the frame or window, but there are 4 targets in the HTML standard who have special functions:
_blank : new window/tab
_self : in the same window or frame
_parent : in the parent window or frame
_top : in the root window or frame

Answer (score 0):

Minor, but I couldn't see a reason why

```
$gravatar = str_replace("[HASH]", $hash, $gravatar);
```

is needed, why not just

```
$gravatar = '<img border="0" alt="Gravatar" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'.$hash.'?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG" height=48 width=48 />';
```

Also I think you're missing an underscore on:

```
target="new"
```

Comment: It was that way because I had all the literal strings in one bit at the top as I was tweaking them.. makes sense to change it to the other way though, thanks. The other one is just a typo.. I'll change them.. Cheers